# Issue uselecting rows with checkmark accessory

Tags: swift

**I have a tableView that gets its data from JSON. It contains a field called Marked:**

```
struct Example: Decodable {

    let marked: Int
}
```

Marked can either be equals 1 or 2. If it is 2 a checkmark accessory should appear when the tableView is loaded and the row should be automatically selected if it is a 1 no accessory should appear.

**In cellForRowAt I make the cells with records that contain 2, show a checkmark:**

```
let Structure: Example

    if (Structure.marked == 2) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
```

**The issue is, when unselecting I am forced to select the row twice, as if it did not already have a checkmark to make the checkmark disappear.**

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        unselect()
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
      }
```

Is it possible to make a checkmark row automatically selected as well?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the struct member as variable

```
struct Example: Decodable {
    var marked: Int
}
```

Use only `didSelectRowAt` (and delete `didDeselectRowAt`), in the method toggle the value in the struct and reload the row, `datasource` represents the data source array.

Basically **never** modify the cell outside of `cellForRow` without updating the model simultaneously

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if datasource[indexPath.row].marked == 2 {
       datasource[indexPath.row].marked = 1
       unselect()
    } else {
       datasource[indexPath.row].marked = 2
       select()
    }
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

If you are responsible for the backend please send `marked` as `Bool`, an `Int` is pretty cumbersome.

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding your method. Where are you removing and adding the checkmarks?

Comment: `tableView.reloadRows` calls `cellForRowAt` which updates the row

Comment: I also need to execute the functions unselect() and select() that apply changes to the records using POST requests, is it possible to implement this into your method?

Comment: Nothing seems to happen no checkmarks are added or removed, I appreciate your help and patience, is there anything that I may have missed?